# Como puedo detener un hilo mediante un procedimiento en C

Tags: c, hilos

Suponiendo que tengo un programa que requiere que use varios `hilos` y en esos `hilos` cargar el mismo proceso ¿Hay algún modo que cuando termine el proceso el `hilo` en el que esta cargado se quede en pausa?

Ejemplo:

```
void *recorre(char[] algo, int num){
//procesos varios
//aca es donde deberia detener el hilo
}


int main (void){
    //declaraciones varias de variebles por aca
    pthread_t t1,t2;
    pthread_create(&t1,NULL,recorre("undicho",2,NULL);
    pthread_create(&t2,NULL,recorre("otro dicho",3,NULL);
    //termina programa
}
```

Espero se entienda.

Comment: Tengo la impresión que la respuesta dependerá del ambiente en donde estás corriendo dicho programa. Podías ahondar mas en ello?

Comment: En ubuntu, podria pegar el segmento de codigo que me genera problemas de ser necesario

Answer (score 1):

Si necesitas que un hilo se *duerma* normalmente es porque el mismo tiene que esperar a que otro hilo diferente le provea cierta información o para evitar que dos hilos accedan a la misma zona crítica de forma simultánea (que viene a ser lo mismo).

Una opción para tratar estos casos pasa por usar un *mutex*. Un *mutex* es una especie de semáforo. Solo permite que un hilo acceda a la sección (o secciones) protegidas y bloque al acceso al resto:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<pthread.h>
#include<unistd.h>

// definicion del bloqueo (uno por region critica)
pthread_mutex_t lock;
int contador = 0;

void* NuevoTrabajo(void* arg)
{
  for( int i=0; i<10; i++ )
  {
    pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);

    int temp = contador + 1;
    sleep(1);
    contador = temp;
    printf("Nuevo trabajo. Hay: %d\n",contador);

    pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);

    sleep(1);
  }

  return NULL;
}

void* ConsumirTrabajo(void* arg)
{
  sleep(2);

  for( int i=0; i<10; i++ )
  {
    pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);

    int temp = contador;
    if( temp > 0 )
    {
      temp--;
      sleep(1);
      contador = temp;
      printf("Trabajo consumido. Quedan: %d\n",contador);
    }
    else i--;

    pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);
  }

  return NULL;
}

int main()
{
  pthread_t t0, t1;

  int err = pthread_create(&t0, NULL, &NuevoTrabajo, NULL);
  if (err != 0)
  {
    printf("Error: %s", strerror(err));
    return 0;
  }

  err = pthread_create(&t1, NULL, &ConsumirTrabajo, NULL);
  if (err != 0)
  {
    printf("Error: %s", strerror(err));
    return 0;
  }

  pthread_join(t0, NULL);
  pthread_join(t1, NULL);
}
```

El código consiste en un programa sencillo con dos hilos: uno que genera trabajos y otro que los consume.

El programa tiene varias características:

- Usa `sleep` para simular cargas de trabajo
- Hace una copia del contador para permitir *lecturas y escrituras sucias* (se verá más adelante).

Si ejecutas el programa podrás obtener una secuencia similar a esta:

```
Nuevo trabajo. Hay: 1
Nuevo trabajo. Hay: 2
Trabajo consumido. Quedan: 1
Trabajo consumido. Quedan: 0
Nuevo trabajo. Hay: 1
Trabajo consumido. Quedan: 0
Nuevo trabajo. Hay: 1
Trabajo consumido. Quedan: 0
...
```

Con lo que se ve cierta coherencia... el número de trabajos únicamente varía de uno en uno.

¿Que sucede si ejecutamos el programa sin guardas?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<pthread.h>
#include<unistd.h>

// definicion del bloqueo (uno por region critica)
pthread_mutex_t lock;
int contador = 0;

void* NuevoTrabajo(void* arg)
{
  for( int i=0; i<10; i++ )
  {
//    pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);

    int temp = contador + 1;
    sleep(1);
    contador = temp;
    printf("Nuevo trabajo. Hay: %d\n",contador);

//    pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);

    sleep(1);
  }

  return NULL;
}

void* ConsumirTrabajo(void* arg)
{
  sleep(2);

  for( int i=0; i<10; i++ )
  {
//    pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);

    int temp = contador;
    if( temp > 0 )
    {
      temp--;
      sleep(1);
      contador = temp;
      printf("Trabajo consumido. Quedan: %d\n",contador);
    }
    else i--;

//    pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);
  }

  return NULL;
}

int main()
{
  pthread_t t0, t1;

  int err = pthread_create(&t0, NULL, &NuevoTrabajo, NULL);
  if (err != 0)
  {
    printf("Error: %s", strerror(err));
    return 0;
  }

  err = pthread_create(&t1, NULL, &ConsumirTrabajo, NULL);
  if (err != 0)
  {
    printf("Error: %s", strerror(err));
    return 0;
  }

  pthread_join(t0, NULL);
  pthread_join(t1, NULL);
}
```

Sucede que ahora el programa se vuelve un poco más caótico:

```
Nuevo trabajo. Hay: 1
Trabajo consumido. Quedan: 0
Nuevo trabajo. Hay: 2
Trabajo consumido. Quedan: 1
Nuevo trabajo. Hay: 3
Trabajo consumido. Quedan: 0
Nuevo trabajo. Hay: 1
Trabajo consumido. Quedan: 0
...
```

Fíjate como ahora se producen saltos en el número de trabajos... esta es la prueba de que las guardas están funcionando correctamente. Las guardas protegen las regiones críticas evitando que los hilos se pisen el trabajo.